# How to setup the project & workspace for building Androlate; an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Does anyone know how to properly setup an Eclipse project in order to build the Androlate plugin; which can be found at http://code.google.com/p/androlate/issues/list?

I need this in order to replace the older Google translation code - which no longer works - with the newer Bing Translation code (see Issue #2 of this plugin for more information).

I've never built an Eclipse plugin before and all my attempts so far for this plugin have failed.  However, I'm able to build the plugin examples given by Eclipse and I've also be able to build the complex Motodev plugin (http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/library/motodev_core_plugins.html); therefore my environment (Eclipse Juno) should be correct.

First, the source for this plugin is lacking its .project File; so I had to trick Eclipse in order to import this project into the workspace by overwriting a new plugin project over the source files.  (BTW, does anyone knows why is it so difficult to simply add an existing project to the current workspace in Eclipse?  Why did they have to make such a simple task so difficult?).

Second, when I try to launch this plugin under Debug Mode as an Eclipse application, I first got multiple error messages: `Can't find bundle for base name feature, locale en_US`.

Finally, when I try the plugin itself, I got the error `Logging bundle must not be null` at the line 60 of the AndrolateWizard.java file; indicating that the call to `Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID)` at the previous line (line 59) return a null bundle.

Comment: If you have the Subclipse plug-in installed on your Eclipse, you ought to be able to create a Subversion project on Eclipse by following the directions on this page.  http://code.google.com/p/androlate/source/checkout

Comment: Oh, I don't have any problem downloading the source code and creating a new plugin project (Eclipse Juno) with this stuff but when comes the time to build and try it; there is something that's not right and the whole project doesn't work at all.  Possibly because this stuff have been made for an older version of Eclipse or because I don't know how to properly configure the project in order to compile it right.  As the creation of a plugin is something that can become rapidly complex, my money is on this last option but I know nothing for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Plugin Id specified in the activator does not match the plugin id specified in your MANIFEST.MF [Check and correct it to com.cicadalane.androlate]

Comment: Thanks, it's working now and I'm now one step further: stuck at the next bug!  (But this is another question!)

Comment: Would be happy to answer that if you ask

Comment: Sorry but it's not necessary any more, it was my error: there is a distinction in the program between the check in a checkbox and its label: to show the list of available items, we must click on the label and not on its check.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the bounty, I was thinking that setting the answer mark was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but here is an androlate gradle plugin if it helps anyone https://github.com/ayvazj/gradle-androlate-plugin